# How to cherry pic and add a second patch to the first cherry picked patch?

Tags: git, patch, gerrit, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I have two branches branch A and branch B in GIT project.
where i have committed a code to branch A which is patch 1.
Then cherry picked patch 1 of branch A to branch B.
later i gave a second patch (patch 2) to the **same commit** in branch A.
How to add this patch 2 of branch A to branch B?

Answer (score 0):

If no other commits are involved, here's a simple solution:

```
git checkout branch-B
git reset HEAD^ --hard
git cherry-pick <same-commit>
```

It will look like no new commit is created on branch-B.

If you don't mind adding a new commit to branch-B, just `git cherry-pick <same-commit>`.

But after you gave a second patch to the same commit, the commit id should be changed. So in fact we have two commits. To be clear, the `<same-commit>` above is actually the second commit id.